Discard missing log file and send email with available files
I wrote a code to perform data replication from one server to another, post successful replication, logs are generated at two path "\\server1\Files" and "\\server1\CAS". the code is working fine  and can send multiple log files as an attachment. The code executes once in a day, there can be a scenario where no new files are available for replication on source server, hence log file for missing files and copied files will not generate but only output log will generate. log file names are in Array.
Now I also want to check that even if any of the log file(s) is not generated or not available at mentioned location/path the remaining availbale log files must be attached and email should be sent.
I wrote below code to send all logs as an attachment in email whihc is working perfectly
   $User = "Email_DL";
   $Recipients = @("user1.xyz.com","user2.xyz.com");
   $Password = "";

   $Attachmentss = @(
                 "\\Server1\Files\FilesMissing.log"
                 "\\Server1\Files\FilesCopied.log"
                 "\\Server1\Files\Output.log"
                 "\\Server1\Files\CAS\CAS_FLDFilesCopied.log"
                 "\\Server1\Files\CAS\CAS_FLDFilesMissing.log"
                 "\\Server1\Files\CAS\CAS_FLD_Output.log"
                );

   Send-MailMessage -From $User -To $Recipients -SMTPServer "XXXXXXXX" -Body " log files" -Subject `
   "Replication test" -Attachments $Attachmentss.

Now What I am looking for is even if any of the log file or files not available/generated even though the available log files in above path should be attached and emailed.
Example: if FilesMissing.log file is not available at path mentioned in above array the remaining files in array must be sent as an attachment, same way for remaining log files, but Output.log and CAS_FLD_Output.log will always generate post script completion. So, if no log files available then output logs should be attached and sent to Recipients.
Please let me know how to do it.

If I understand the question properly, the two files Output.log and CAS_FLD_Output.log wil always exist, even if none of the other files can be found.
In that case, I would suggest using a Where-Object clause to filter for only existing files in the predefined array.
Also, since I hate those nasty backticks in code, I wil use Splatting the parameters for commands that can take a lot of parameters.
$User       = 'Email_DL'
$Recipients = 'user1.xyz.com','user2.xyz.com'
$logFiles   = '\\Server1\Files\FilesMissing.log',
              '\\Server1\Files\FilesCopied.log',
              '\\Server1\Files\Output.log',
              '\\Server1\Files\CAS\CAS_FLDFilesCopied.log',
              '\\Server1\Files\CAS\CAS_FLDFilesMissing.log',
              '\\Server1\Files\CAS\CAS_FLD_Output.log'

# test if the files exist. As I understand it, both
# Output.log and CAS_FLD_Output.log will Always exist, so
# $Attachments will at least always contain these two file paths
$Attachments = $logFiles | Where-Object { (Test-Path -Path $_) }

# use splatting to Send-MailMessage by creating a Hashtable with the parameters
$mailParams = @{
    From        = $User
    To          = $Recipients
    SMTPServer  = 'XXXXXXXX'
    Body        = 'log files'
    Subject     = 'Replication test'
    Attachments = $Attachments
    # add more parameters here when needed
}
# send the email
Send-MailMessage @mailParams

You may consider using parameter -LiteralPath instead of -Path on the Test-Path command to avoid errors when path and filenames could contain characters like [ or ]

You might want to add the $NonExistingLogFiles = $logFiles | Where-Object { -Not(Test-Path  -Path $_) }  (if needed)

I forgot to add that this might be needed to know which files did get checked on sending the mail.

@Luuk If it were my report, then I would certainly mention the non-existing logs in the email body. As it is, the OP is not clear about this at all and makes no mention of it in the question, so..

your code worked perfectly

This isn't too bad, you just need to cycle through the list of files and verify they exist, and then add them to you array of attachments if they exist.
 $desiredAttachments = @(
                 "\\Server1\Files\FilesMissing.log"
                 "\\Server1\Files\FilesCopied.log"
                 "\\Server1\Files\Output.log"
                 "\\Server1\Files\CAS\CAS_FLDFilesCopied.log"
                 "\\Server1\Files\CAS\CAS_FLDFilesMissing.log"
                 "\\Server1\Files\CAS\CAS_FLD_Output.log"
                );

$actualAttachments = @();
$missingFiles = @();

foreach($file in $desiredAttachments){
   $fileExists = Test-path $file -quiet

   if($fileExists){
      $actualAttachments += $file
   }
   else{
      Write-output "File $file was not present"
      $missingFiles += $file
   }
}

Then update your code to use $actualAttachments as the attachment and include $missingFiles to denote that those files were not present or weren't found.

Implemented the suggested code and found that if all log files in array available the  value is getting stored in $missingFiles and $actualAttachments array is empty. Where as it should be like whatever .log files are available from $desiredAttachments should be stored in $actualAttachments and missing files in $missingFiles
